# Link that is domain-relative but protocol-specific

Tags: url, hyperlink, uri

Is there a way to link to a resource in a domain-relative but protocol-specific way?

For instance, consider a link on the site `http://example.com`

```
<a href="/home/">...</a>
```

This links to:
http://example.com/home/ if the page you are on is on the HTTP protocol. 
https://example.com/home/ if the page you are on is on the HTTPS protocol.

```
<a href="http://example.com/home/">...</a>
```

This links to:
`http://example.com/home/` always

Is there a way to link to the HTTP version of the site without explicitly stating the full domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in [RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.4.2), and the answer supports some of my blind attempts. There is a backwards compatability feature with a previous spec which allows you to specify the scheme if and only if it matches your current scheme. In these cases, if you are linking from `http://example.com`, the URL `http:home` will link to `http://example.com/home`, however `https:home` will link to `https://home/`.

> Some parsers allow the scheme name to be present in a relative
> reference if it is the same as the base URI scheme.  This is
> considered to be a loophole in prior specifications of partial URI
> [RFC1630].  Its use should be avoided but is allowed for backward
> compatibility.
>
> ```
>   "http:g"        =  "http:g"         ; for strict parsers
>                   /  "http://a/b/c/g" ; for backward compatibility
> ```